# Select a single column from single Row Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am developing an application using Java and Hibernate.

Now, there is a Table Empdata and let's say two among its many columns are uid(primary key) and effort.

Now using Hibernate, I want to extract effort for a specific uid.

How will I do so using Hibernate?

Comment: When you are having a `@Entity` representing the rows, you can either use a `@NamedQuery` with HQL or use the criteria API.

Comment: @Smutje, please elaborate....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a method that takes `uid` as argument and returns an `effort`.

```
public Effort getEffort(Integer uid){
    Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT e.effort FROM Empdata e WHERE e.uid=:uid");
    query.setParameter("uid", uid);
    return query.uniqueResult();
}
```

Here I took the assumption that `effort is of type Effort` and `uid is of type Integer`

Comment: Yes, this was very helpful. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

In HQL you can use list() function to get a list of Object[] array that contains result rows:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select e.uid from Empdata  e");
List<Object[]> rows = query.list();
```

in returned array 1-st element will be id, second - name.

```
for (Object[] row: rows) {
    System.out.println(" ------------------- ");
    System.out.println("id: " + row[0]);        
}
```

Edit: Another answer to another question:

```
String hql = "from Empdata where firstname= :fn";    
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("fn", "Saad");
query.setMaxResults(1);
Effort ef = (Effort) query.uniqueResult();
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I want only a single data corresponding to a particular value of primary key (and use something like uniqueResult() ), what should I do?

Comment: sql would be like "select e.uid from Empdata e where firstname=abc"

Comment: something like that?

Comment: Yes!! 
In this case, firstname is the primary key

Comment: @FarazDurrani. You should use query.setParameter instead of direct assigning value in query. It is a security threat ...And when you apply any code review tool on your project it will also give you this type of error

Answer (score 2):

using  uniqueResult() you can get single object.Here is single line java statement.

HQ:- it should contain Empdata as entity class

```
public Effort getEffort(int uid){
return  session.createQuery("SELECT e.effort FROM Empdata e WHERE e.uid=:uid").setParameter("uid", uid).uniqueResult();
}
```

SQL:- No entity class required

```
public Effort getEffort(int uid){
return session.createSQLQuery("SELECT column1 FROM EMP e WHERE e.uid=:uid").setParameter("uid", uid).uniqueResult();
}
```